# Linear regulator dropping too much voltage on load

Tags: voltage, linear

I'm trying to get around 4V for a project from a 5V input, but while following the designs in http://www.telit.com/fileadmin/user_upload/products/Downloads/3G/Telit_UL865_Hardware_User_Guide_r7.pdf page 28 as well as http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/1528fb.pdf and none of the resistor combinations or even strict adherence to the low ESR caps, and still when ever there is a load put on it, the voltage drops at least half a volt.

Without a load, I get from the linear site's resistor configuration, 3.95V. I put a 20Ω resistor on there which should be just under a fifth of an amp, but then the voltage measured across the resistor lowers considerably more than what the datasheet indicates it should, and the actual load I measure matches the new voltage divided by the resistance. For instance, I just measured it at 3.38V.

I checked the power supply, which is just an ATX attached to a breakout, and there are no anomalies there.

I've tried varying the capacitance on both input and output, but the behavior is the same either way.

I've also measured the input pin to make sure it's getting sufficient voltage, and the sense pin is 3.27V which is probably around where it needs to be.

I've also tried swapping out the regulator with another one, but that doesn't really help.

This is frustrating.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fe7ckH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Please anyone tell me if there are some pit falls with this particular linear regulator, or can anyone suggest a better circuit, preferably one where the regulator comes in through hole rather than surface mount?

Update

Well, it's not quite perfect, but soldering it did lower the drop, so now it's going from 3.93 with just the 10μf cap on the input, and the 100μf on the output, down to 3.76V when I put the 20Ω resistor on there.

That still seems kind of high, it should be closer to 3.8.

Unfortunately, I don't have an oscilloscope at this time to view the output as others have suggested.

Comment: Your first link is broken. Can you add a schematic showing *exactly what you're doing*? Without that, all is guesswork.

Comment: @MarcusMüller sorry about that. Link is fixed, and a schematic is made. I did try other values of resistors and caps.

Comment: Looks like your circuit matches the LT1528 datasheet, so it's a bit puzzling. Maybe add an input bypass capacitor? Under load, is the sense voltage still 3.3V or does it drop too?

Comment: Where did you buy the LT device from?

Comment: @KenShirriff The sense doesn't change under load. How much capacitance be for the input bypass cap? Is this just another one added to in and gnd?

Comment: @Andyaka I got them from Digi-key

Comment: You need to get an oscilloscope on the input voltage to make sure it isn't dipping low with some kind of transient behavior that is upsetting the LT1528.

Comment: from where to where do you connect the 20 Ω load ?

Comment: @MarcusMüller between the out and the ground.

Comment: The datasheet says to bypass the input pin to ground if the device   is more than six inches away from the main input filter capacitor, but they don't give a value.

Comment: @integral - Oh dear. I was going to add some more comments to your [previous identical question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/273825/lt1528-voltage-drop-too-low), which you deleted. There were at least 18 comments on there, including mine, but all that help and troubleshooting knowledge has now been lost. Therefore people are repeating the same suggestions here, because they cannot see that they are duplicating work from your previous question :-( Deleting a question and then repeating it, is *never* a good plan.

Comment: @SamGibson noted and sorry about that. won't happen again.

Comment: "*but then the voltage measured across the resistor lowers considerably more than what the datasheet indicates it should*" How much do you get *exactly*?

Comment: @dim according to linear technology's dropout chart, no less than 3.7V. It's often 3.5V or 3.2V.

Comment: You're contradicting yourself: if the sense pin is at 3.27 V, then Vout is at 3.27V*(330+68)/330= 3.94V, unless your voltage divider is somhow broken. And @dim didn't ask for the datasheet value, but for how much you actually measured.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I'm not contradicting myself at all. I'm saying, without a load, in my case I used a 20Ohm resistor when I did use a load, the voltage is 3.95. It's when I put a load on there that the voltage drops significantly, and that's the whole problem. There is supposed to be some dropout when a load is applied, but not that much.

Comment: ok, but what is *drops significantly* in hard numbers, i.e. Volts?!

Comment: @MarcusMüller it varies, I've seen it go as high as 3.55 to as low as 3.2. I just did a test right now and it's 3.38.

Comment: add that info to the question!

Comment: @MarcusMüller ok done.

Comment: hm, while you're measuring things, can you measure the voltage at the "in" pin? How much is it?

Comment: @MarcusMüller 5.0V

Comment: So, the point is that we all agree that the circuit you show *should* work. My very best guess is that the breadboard's at fault. Please make sure the GND pins of all components that are grounded properly connect to ground, the resistance between the sense and the out pin is actually as you've drawn it etc.

Comment: @MarcusMüller just checked. Everything is that is supposed to be grounded is. I checked the resistors; they are the values they are supposed to be and connected to the pins they are supposed to be. I even went so far as to shift the pieces over, and still the same problem.

Comment: If you have a scope, check and see what the output looks like.  I (stupidly) put a very low ESR ceramic capacitor on the output of a 4931 instead of the specified tantalum, and my multimeter showed about 3V instead of 3.3V.  The scope showed the output of the regulator oscillating - it produced a really sharp sawtooth wave.  Get out the scope and eyeball things.

Comment: @JRE I'll put that on my list of things to get.

Comment: @MarcusMüller the breadboard was indeed at fault. I was able to get it to work even without tantalum caps, so that's a plus.

Comment: Just curious, how did you fix it?  Move to a stripboard or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to bring this to a good, visible conclusion:

I wrote:

> So, the point is that we all agree that the circuit you show should work. My very best guess is that the breadboard's at fault. Please make sure the GND pins of all components that are grounded properly connect to ground, the resistance between the sense and the out pin is actually as you've drawn it etc.

And you later [confirmed](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/275875/linear-regulator-dropping-too-much-voltage-on-load?noredirect=1#comment625269_275875) in your comments:

> The breadboard was indeed at fault. I was able to get it to work even without tantalum caps, so that's a plus.

So as usual, breadboards aren't the tool of choice if you're seeing spurious problems.